# How do I route traffic in k3s with traefik to app

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, rancher, k3s

I'm new to traefik and k3s, I imagined it to be mature so I can install it easily without problems. But I struggle with it. I installed k3s with traefik and from what I've read/googled so far, after adding service+deployment+ingress, it should just work. but it does not :frowning:
I must be missing something basic, hope you can point me to the problem or link some tutorial/docs I missed.

So after installing k3s with traefik (default), there is this deployment version: `rancher/mirrored-library-traefik:2.9.4`.

I have a django app, for which service looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-sandbox-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    name: web-sandbox
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 80
    name: HTTP
```

deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-sandbox
  labels:
    app: web-sandbox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0%
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 120
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-sandbox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-sandbox
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: registry.gitlab.com/lucas03/digrin-sandbox:commit
          name: web-sandbox
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: digrin-sandbox-secret
          command: ['/bin/sh', 'extras/docker-entrypoint.sh']
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: gunicorn
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /robots.txt
              port: 8000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 3
            failureThreshold: 9
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /robots.txt
              port: 8000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 2
            failureThreshold: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 2
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-credentials
```

I believe web-sandbox is running, as I don't see errors and I see logs with robots.txt path being hit by healthcheck.
I thought that I just need to add a ingress object like this and after pointing my subdomain to the IP of the server, it will work:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-sandbox-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "5"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: "100"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "traefik"
  rules:
  - host: sandbox.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-sandbox-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

When I hit the sandbox.mydomain.com it responds with `404 page not found`. I wanted to somehow debug this with curl image. But if I wanna hit by pod IP/name e.g. `curl HTTPcurl http://10.43.108.170:8000/robots.txt` or `curl http://web-sandbox:8000/robots.txt` it just responds: `Couldn't connect to server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, so I misunderstood ports binding. When I set `targetPort: 8000` on service.yaml and `port number: 8000` in ingress.yaml, it works. I thought I had to create port forward 80 to 8000 somewhere :confused: I guess ingress handles that automatically